# error mismatch VBA

Tags: windows, vba, excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YOXu.png)I'm getting hard time figuring what is going on in my code. It keeps saying "run-time error:'13' ". How can I handle this error?

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rearr(), wrarr()
Dim fName As String
Dim rowno As Long, colno As Long, rec As Long
Dim cnt As Long, cnt2 As Long
Dim delim As String

'specify output sheet
Set ws = Worksheets("1.Locations")
'specify text file to read (.csv in this example)
fName = "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\names.csv"
'set text file delimiter
delim = "," 'for Tab delimiter use delim = Chr(9)
ifnum = FreeFile
'set start row/col for text data to be placed ("A1" in this example)
rowno = 3  'row 1
colno = 2  'col A

    With ws
        Open fName For Input Access Read As #ifnum
            rec = 0
                Do While Not EOF(ifnum)
                    Line Input #ifnum, tmpvar
                    rec = rec + 1
                    'Put whole record into array
                    ReDim Preserve rearr(1 To rec)
                    rearr(rec) = tmpvar
                    'Split fields into a second array
                    wrarr = Split(rearr(rec), delim)
                    cnt2 = UBound(wrarr)
                        'Write fields out to specified ws range, one row per record
                        For cnt = 0 To cnt2
                            ws.Cells(rowno, colno + cnt) = wrarr(cnt)
                        Next cnt
                     rowno = rowno + 1
                Loop
            Close #ifnum
    End With
```

Comment: `ifnum = FreeFile` neither of these exist.

Comment: Where did you declare ifnum?

Comment: @Zerk Technically, they _do_ exist... As implicit variables. ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213953/import-a-specific-text-file-into-excel-spreadsheet-using-vba

Comment: @Zerk, [`FreeFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/freefile-function) is a function which returns the free file number for `Input` and `Ouput`

Comment: Dan - The error is likely that there is not a worksheet called "1.Locations" in the currently active workbook. @CallumDA thanks!

Comment: @CallumDA i followed the code in the link above but it is not working, could you help me in understanding the code ??

Comment: @zerk nope there is a sheet named "1.Locations" in my workbook, what does "13" means ? the line where there is the error ? or it is the error code ?

Comment: Error code type mismatch

Comment: It's an error code. It relates to the description of *type mismatch*

Comment: @dan, it's not the best code, in truth. But yes, you need to specify the worksheet to put the data (from the text file) onto.

Comment: oh ok, when i try to change the worksheet name ("Locations") it is now giving me error  code 9 subscription out of range

Comment: in my spreadsheet i have 2 worksheet one named "VPR solver console" and the other "1.Locations". How am i suppose to refer them ? by name or by "Sheet1","Sheet2" etc..? @CallumDa

Comment: @Dan You can refer to the worksheets as `Worksheets("1.Locations")`.  And, maybe I missed it, but what line does the debugger stop when it shows the error message?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld the IDE where I'm writing my code is the standard IDE provided with excel.. It is not showing where is the bug it is just displaying this error message..

Comment: @RonRosenfeld if you know a way how to show the error on line, please show me

Comment: Does the error message appear in a dialog box, with "debug" being one of the options?

Comment: nope it is in a messagebox with ok and help as option

Comment: I've not seen that. Usually the options are continue, end, debug, help.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?  and What are the options checked in Tools/Options/General Error Trapping

Comment: @RonRosenfeld ive uploaded a link to an image in my post, please take a look :(

Comment: @Dan Is your code in a regular module, or in a worksheet or workbook module?

Comment: Code should usually be in a regular module, and the error trapping should be set to "break on unhandled errors".  If you have the code in a worksheet module, with that same error-trapping setting, you will get the kind of dialog box you show.

Comment: ermm i don't know, basically what i've done is i've created a command button with the design toolin the worksheet then double clicked on the command button and then edit code :(

Comment: OK, that puts the code into a worksheet module.  Go to Tools/Options/General and change Error Trapping to `Break on All Errors`.  That should give you the standard error dialog with a debug option

Comment: ah now i get the source error

Comment: wrarr = Split(rearr(rec), delim)

Comment: Examine the contents of `rearr(rec)` and `delim` after you hit the debug button.  You can see delim and rearr in the locals window, and rec will refer to an item number in that array.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld the content of my textfile seems to be present in the array and delim has been assigned to value ","

Comment: @RonRosenfeld one last thing :/ the values are showing along a row not within the column mentioned :( any final help?

Comment: Examine your line `ws.Cells(rowno, colno + cnt) = wrarr(cnt)`.  Once you understand what it is doing, the fix should be apparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced your error.

In your declarations, change

```
Dim wrarr()
```

to

```
Dim wrarr
```

Comment: Sometimes it is the subtle differences in variable declarations that are important.  But most important was defining the line which was causing the error.